# STPopUpController pass clicked data to bottom sheet style iOS

Tags: ios

I am facing a problem in passing data to STPopUp Bottom sheet

So now there is map in my application that consists of pins. once the user click the pins, it should display the information of clicked pin to the STPopupController. I can retrieve the data of clicked pins, but i have been figuring out how to pass the data of clicked pin to the bottom sheet for quite a while.

here are some of my codes in my first controller

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
NSString *outletName = store.displayName;
NSString *address    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@", store.addressLine1, store.addressLine2, store.addressLine3, store.addressLine4, store.postcode, store.city, store.country];
NSString *contactNumber = store.contactNumber;

STPopupController *popupController = [[STPopupController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OutletInformationViewController"]];
popupController.style = STPopupStyleBottomSheet;
[popupController presentInViewController:self];
}
```

The OutletInformationViewController is another view controller.

Basically the bottom sheet is already there, but i can't display the data of clicked pin.

Please don't mind about how i get the data. All the data of clicked pin is already there. What i am struggling about is how to pass this data into the bottom sheet controller.

Can somebody guide me please? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to import OutletInformationViewController.h in your current view controller

```
#import "OutletInformationViewController.h"
```

Then, create a property in `OutletInformationViewController.h` which is the data your need to pass.
Next, separate this line:

```
STPopupController *popupController = [[STPopupController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OutletInformationViewController"]];
```

into this:

```
OutletInformationViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OutletInformationViewController"];
controller.clickedData = clickedData; // Pass the data here
STPopupController *popupController = [[STPopupController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
```

Comment: Emma Watson, you rock! Thanks! saved my day

Comment: No worries. Glad that it helps.